# Select disappears on change in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, select, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-9

Having a really odd problem with IE9 and the select dropdown I've created.

It only happens in IE9, which is really weird.

Basically, there are multiple dropdowns on the page (4 total). When you click on one of them, and select an option from the dropdown, the parent dropdown then disappears from the page, and from what I can see, the DOM as well.

This happens when you select an option from any of the dropdowns. I've narrowed it to IE9 only, which is crazy cause it works fine in IE8

**HTML**

```
<div id="news7" style="width: 650px; overflow:hidden;">
  <h2 class="h2-3">20' DEEP</h2>
  <select name="booth-images" id="booth-dropdown" class="booth-images showName">
    <option value="">-- Select an option from the dropdown</option>
    <option value="http://enkshows.com/img/enkexhibitors/20X13FRONTsm.jpg" data-dimension="20X13">20X13</option>
    <option value="http://enkshows.com/img/enkexhibitors/20X15FRONTsm.jpg" data-dimension="20X15">20X15</option>
    <option value="http://enkshows.com/img/enkexhibitors/20X20FRONTsm.jpg" data-dimension="20X20">20X20</option>
    <option value="http://enkshows.com/img/enkexhibitors/20X23FRONTsm.jpg" data-dimension="20X23">20X23</option>
    <option value="http://enkshows.com/img/enkexhibitors/20X26FRONTsm.jpg" data-dimension="20X26">20X26</option>
    <option value="http://enkshows.com/img/enkexhibitors/20X30FRONTsm.jpg" data-dimension="20X30">20X30</option>
    <option value="http://enkshows.com/img/enkexhibitors/20X36FRONTsm.jpg" data-dimension="20X46">20X46</option>
    <option value="http://enkshows.com/img/enkexhibitors/20X40FRONTsm.jpg" data-dimension="20X40">20X40</option>
    <option value="http://enkshows.com/img/enkexhibitors/20X50FRONTsm.jpg" data-dimension="20X50">20X50</option>
  </select>
  <div class="image-display"></div>   
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").each(function(){
        $(this).on('change', function(){
            var src = $(this).val();
            var imageSrc = "http://enkshows.com/img/enkexhibitors/";
            var title = $(this).find(":selected").data("dimension");
            var url = "<a rel='shadowbox' title='" + title + "' href='" + imageSrc + title + "FRONT.jpg' target='_blank'><img src='" + src + "'></a>";
            var title = "<p><a href='" + src + "' >" + title + "</a><p>"

            var $this = $(this);
            var $image = $(".image-display");
            var $imageDisplay = $(this).parent().find(".image-display");

            if ($this.val() == "") {
                $image.removeClass('active');
            } else {
                $image.removeClass('active').hide();
                $imageDisplay.addClass('active').show();
                $this.parent().find(".image-display a").not(":selected").remove();
                $this.parent().find(".image-display p").not(":selected").remove();
                $imageDisplay.addClass('active-display').append(url, title);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Also, sorry if the JS is sloppy. I'm a newb, trying to get better so I am totally open to a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#news7").on('change','select', function(){
            var src = $(this).val();
            var imageSrc = "http://enkshows.com/img/enkexhibitors/";
            var title = $(this).attr("data-dimension");
            var url = "<a rel='shadowbox' title='" + title + "' href='" + imageSrc + title + "FRONT.jpg' target='_blank'><img src='" + src + "'></a>";
            var title = "<p><a href='" + src + "' >" + title + "</a><p>"

            var $this = $(this);
            var $image = $(".image-display");
            var $imageDisplay = $(this).closest("#news7").find(".image-display");

            if ($this.val() == "") {
                $image.removeClass('active');
            } else {
                $image.removeClass('active').hide();
                $imageDisplay.addClass('active').show();
                $this.closest("#news7").find(".image-display a").not(":selected").remove();
                $this.closest("#news7").find(".image-display p").not(":selected").remove();
                $imageDisplay.addClass('active-display').append(url, title);
            }
        });

});
```

Comment: `$(this).closest("div")` ?!

Comment: @Rituraj 

Thanks for the update. This is a lot cleaner. Why do we not need the $.each(); function?

Comment: $(this).closest("#news7"). by this we reach on #news div then we find desired element parent is not good as compared to closest

Comment: @patrick $("#news7").on('change','select', ...

by this it get all select element there is no need to apply each 
by $(this) we get selected val() as you do in your code

Comment: @Riturajratan but as IDs must be unique on context page, $this.closest("#news7") will work only for one element (select child of #news7 container) and BTW, could/should be wrote `$('#news7').find(...)`. Now if OP has duplicate IDs, that's an other issue that he needs to fix formely

Comment: @A.Wolff thanks for the focus i am trying to giving the answer according to currently asked question

Comment: @Riturajratan It doesn't actually work, though.

It grabs the first element (because it's using an ID) and displays an image for that particular selection, but doesn't trigger an event for any other element on the page.